# How I modify this php while loop?

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am trying to display some images dynamically from a mysql table.

This is what  I tried it with PHP and its working for me.

```
// Fetch all the records:
while ($stmt->fetch()) {

    $html  = "  <div class='row-fluid custom'>\n";
    $html .= "      <div class='span6'>\n";
    $html .= "      <img src='images/{$image}'>\n";
    $html .= "      </div>\n";                                                              
    $html .= "  </div>\n";

    //Add images to array
    $images[] = $html;              
}
```

And this is the markup from above PHP:

```
<div class='row-fluid custom'>
    <div class='span6'>
        <img src='images/cond-1.png'>
    </div>                                                                  
</div>  
<div class='row-fluid custom'>
    <div class='span6'>
        <img src='images/cond-2.png'>
    </div>                                                                  
</div>  
<div class='row-fluid custom'>
    <div class='span6'>
        <img src='images/cond-3.png'>
    </div>                                                                  
</div>  
<div class='row-fluid custom'>
    <div class='span6'>
        <img src='images/cond-4.png'>
    </div>                                                                  
</div>
```

But my problem is, when I am going to modify above Markup to like below.

```
<div class="row-fluid custom">
    <div class="span6">
        <img src="images/cond-1.png">
    </div>                                  
    <div class="span6">
        <img src="images/cond-2.png">
    </div>                                  
</div>                              
<div class="row-fluid custom">
    <div class="span6">
        <img src="images/cond-3.png">
    </div>                                  
    <div class="span6">
        <img src="images/cond-4.png">
    </div>                                  
</div>
```

Actually I need to group two images inside `row-fluid` DIVs when displaying my images.

Can anybody tell me how I create like that markup using php?

Hope somebody may help me out.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the [modulus function](http://php.net/manual/en/internals2.opcodes.mod.php) as in this [example](http://phpfiddle.org/lite/code/5ju5-cx72):

```
$images = array('foo.jpg', 'bar.jpg','baz.jpg','glorp.jpg');

$html = '';

for($i = 0; $i < count($images); $i++){
    if($i % 2 == 0) {
         $html .= "  <div class='row-fluid custom'>\n"; 
         $html .= "      <div class='span6'>\n"; 
         $html .= "      <img src='images/{$images[$i]}'>\n"; 
         $html .= "      </div>\n";   
    } else {
        $html .= "      <div class='span6'>\n"; 
        $html .= "      <img src='images/{$images[$i]}'>\n"; 
        $html .= "      </div>\n";   
        $html .= "   </div>\n";
    }
}
echo $html;
```

Using modulus against 2 will allow you to decide which output needs to be appended to the `$html` variable. A result of 0 indicates the number (row) is divisible by 2, allowing you to output the beginning of the div. Any other result allows you to output the end of the div.

Comment: `for` loop or `while' loop do I need to use?

Comment: You should use a `for` loop. You can `fetchAll()` into am array and then loop through the array.

Answer (score 3):

Still use while loop

```
$i = 0;
while ($stmt->fetch()) {
    $html  = "";
    if($i % 2 == 0) $html  = "  <div class='row-fluid custom'>\n";
    $html .= "      <div class='span6'>\n";
    $html .= "      <img src='images/{$image}'>\n";
    $html .= "      </div>\n";                                                              
    if($i++ % 2 == 1) $html .= "  </div>\n";

    //Add images to array
    $images[] = $html;              
}
```

Answer (score 1):

simply add a condition to open/close `div`:

```
$open_div=true;
while ($stmt->fetch()) {
    if( $open_div )
         $html  = "  <div class='row-fluid custom'>\n";
    $html .= "      <div class='span6'>\n";
    $html .= "      <img src='images/{$image}'>\n";
    $html .= "      </div>\n";  
    if( $open_div = !$open_div )                                                            
        $html .= "  </div>\n";
    //Add images to array
    $images[] = $html;              
}
```

As a side-note, your code introduces many `white-spaces` that add up to the total page size and increase download time of the page.